# Fetch dynamically category id from view to model | Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

controller.php

```
$data["category_products"] = $this->product_model->get_products_by_category_id();
```

model.php

```
    //get products by category ID
public function get_products_by_category_id()
{
    $lc_key = get_location_cache_key($this);
    $key = "special_offers_lang_" . $this->selected_lang->id;
    $result_cache = get_cached_data($this, $key, "pr");
    if (!empty($result_cache)) {
        if (!empty($result_cache[$lc_key])) {
            return $result_cache[$lc_key];
        }
    } else {
        $result_cache = array();
    }

    $this->build_query();
    $this->db->where('products.category_id', 1);
    $this->db->order_by('products.created_at', 'DESC')->limit(20);
    $result = $this->db->get('products')->result();

    $result_cache[$lc_key] = $result;
    set_cache_data($this, $key, $result_cache, "pr");
    return $result;
}
```

view.php

```
<?php foreach ($category_products as $product): ?>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

with this function I can get products from  category ID 1.

is any way use this one function and pass from view to model variable which category I need to get in foreach?

or anyother way?

example some like:

```
  <?php foreach ($category_products[1] as $product): ?>
    
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

or

```
 <?php foreach ($category_products[2] as $product): ?>
    
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

@update:

view

```
<?php foreach ($this->product_model->get_products_by_category_id(1) as $product): ?>
```

controller:

```
$data["category_products"] = $this->product_model->get_products_by_category_id($id);
```

model:

```
//get products by category ID
    public function get_products_by_category_id($id)
    {
        $lc_key = get_location_cache_key($this);
        $key = "special_offers_lang_" . $this->selected_lang->id;
        $result_cache = get_cached_data($this, $key, "pr");
        if (!empty($result_cache)) {
            if (!empty($result_cache[$lc_key])) {
                return $result_cache[$lc_key];
            }
        } else {
            $result_cache = array();
        }

        $this->build_query();
        $this->db->where('products.category_id', $id);
        $this->db->order_by('products.created_at', 'DESC')->limit(20);
        $result = $this->db->get('products')->result();

        $result_cache[$lc_key] = $result;
        set_cache_data($this, $key, $result_cache, "pr");
        return $result;
    }
```

this working correct and give me correct output. But also I get issue:

```
Message: Undefined variable: id

Filename: controllers/Home_controller.php
```

when I delete ID from :

```
$data["category_products"] = $this->product_model->get_products_by_category_id();
```

then website down:

```
Type: ArgumentCountError

Message: Too few arguments to function Product_model::get_products_by_category_id(), 0 passed in /home/design/domains/public_html/application/controllers/Home_controller.php on line 34 and exactly 1 expected
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't advise passing an id from the view to the model (the view should not interact with the model directly), but you can pass an id from the controller to the model to specify which category you want, and then pass the result to the view.

Change the `get_products_by_category_id` function to accept an `$id` argument, and use that `$id` in the `WHERE` clause:

model.php

```
    //get products by category ID
public function get_products_by_category_id($id)
{
    $lc_key = get_location_cache_key($this);
    $key = "special_offers_lang_" . $this->selected_lang->id;
    $result_cache = get_cached_data($this, $key, "pr");
    if (!empty($result_cache)) {
        if (!empty($result_cache[$lc_key])) {
            return $result_cache[$lc_key];
        }
    } else {
        $result_cache = array();
    }

    $this->build_query();
    $this->db->where('products.category_id', $id);
    $this->db->order_by('products.created_at', 'DESC')->limit(20);
    $result = $this->db->get('products')->result();

    $result_cache[$lc_key] = $result;
    set_cache_data($this, $key, $result_cache, "pr");
    return $result;
}
```

Then in the controller, pass the id of the category you want to the function:

controller.php

```
$data["category_products"] = $this->product_model->get_products_by_category_id(1); // for category ID 1
```

or

```
$data["category_products"] = $this->product_model->get_products_by_category_id(2); // for category ID 2
```

The view stays the same.

Comment: yes, but in this way I need to each time add in controller example:

Comment: $data["category_products_1"] = $this->product_model->get_products_by_category_id(1); // for category ID 1     $data["category_products_2"] = $this->product_model->get_products_by_category_id(2); // for category ID 2 etc. I need to each time duplicate function in controller. This  is project SAAS and  customers not have access to controller and model, only to view files template.

Comment: and now how to solve it: to dynamically get all ID categories without access to controller and model and display selected categories using variables in view

Comment: If you really want to access the model from the view, keep the changes to the model I described above, and then in the view do: `<?php foreach ($this->product_model->get_products_by_category_id(1) as $product): ?> ... <?php endforeach ?>`

Comment: can you please check my update.

Comment: For your update, either always pass in an `id` when calling the function, or give the function a default `id`, like this: `public function get_products_by_category_id($id = 1)`